# format number to one decimal place during transition? (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to work with d3.js formatting but I'm struggling to get the number to only transition to one decimal place.

Please see the example below;

http://plnkr.co/edit/bEpl8wbA3kzsyakGNJZR?p=preview

Throughout the transition and also at the end I would like it to only be to one decimal place, so at the end of my example it should show 4.4 and not 4.4162.

Here is my code;

```
var formatPercent = d3.format("1r");
var start_val = 0;

var data = 4.4162


d3.selectAll(".textTransition")
  .append("div")
  .text(start_val)
  .attr("class", "percentage")
  .transition()
  .duration(1200)
  .tween(".percentage", function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, data);
    return function(t) {
      d3.select(this).text(formatPercent(i(t)));
    };
  });
```

I am using d3 v3 btw.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Comment: should probably use format of `0.1f`

Comment: the `r` format code is for significant digits, not fixed point notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the line

```
d3.select(this).text(formatPercent(i(t)));
```

to

```
d3.select(this).text(parseFloat(formatPercent(i(t))).toFixed(1));
```

with the following

```
parseFloat(number goes here).toFixed(1);
```

being the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

```
var roundedData = (Math.round(data * 10))/10;
```

Moves the decimal one place, rounds it then moves decimal back to where it should be.

Does that help?